# c++ math lib what happen when domain error?

Tags: c++, c

According to the [asin document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/asin/) , I'm still not clear about the behavior: beside the errno being set, is there any exception thrown, or segmentation fault, or silently, or it's UB, or it's compiler/system/runtime defined?

I'm debugging my program, which crash on client's machines. According to the coredump file, it finally crashed inside a function with many math lib functions. It's possible that the client pass in some invalid value that leads to domain error, that's my bad not to check the input value. But before fixing this issue, I want to first confirm the behavior of domain error, if it's guaranteed to handle it silently, then the crash might be caused by other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally prefer cppreference.com over cplusplus.com.

According to [the cppreference asin documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/asin), std::asin will not throw any exceptions. It will, on domain error, return NaN (if supported) or some other "implementation defined value" and set errno as you said.

According to the C++ standard, the contents of `<cmath>` are the same as in C (for the most part), so I'd strongly assume that they wont throw because of this as well.

If it was able to throw an exception, the page I linked would have a section titled "Exceptions". Generally cppreference is the de-facto standard reference.